# Consistent spacing for variable number of inline divs

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have two divs, divA and divB. Depending on the input received, these divs are either both displayed, neither displayed, or mutually-exclusively displayed. If they are both displayed, I would like them to be spaced in the parent container like so:

```
 -----------------------
|       A       B       |
 -----------------------
```

If only one is displayed, it should just be centered:

```
 -----------------------
|           A           |
 -----------------------
```

This should scale for 'n' number of inline divs. I don't want to use JS, just HTML/CSS.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple code like this:

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px dashed #555;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.A, .B, .C {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 30px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

Removing divs A, B or C will align the rest.

JSFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/yu0n2ofb/

Comment: What if I want fluid widths for containers?